# Correct rewrite rule for site moving from mysite.com to mysite.com/subdirectory (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I'm moving a site from mysite.com to mysite.com/subdirectory.

On the old location, it had a .htcaccesfile (in the root), doing just the basic stuff:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Remove last / if nothing comes after
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

On the new location, I added the same .htaccess-file to the new directory "root" (mysite.com/subdirectory).

After the move, the **Force HTTPS**-function still works, but none of the other ones do.

How do I teach the .htaccess-file to apply the same rulesets to the subdirectory?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: @starkeen the rerwrite filters simply aren't being applied - before I moved the .htaccess file (and the build), the last / was removed correctly, .html filenames where removed correctly, and attempts to direct to /filename.html rewrote the url to /filename. And now it doesn't. Hence, I am not experiencing an error; the expected output just isn't happening.

Comment: If your htaccess and other files are located in a subfolder then your Rewrite path should be `/subfolder/$1` instead of `/$1.html` .